# Unity: How to stop object from spinning when rotating towards object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

When I try to rotate an object towards a point, it starts spinning, but I want it to be able to freely spin, while still rotating towards that point. I can't just clamp the y rotation, because obviously it's already rotating towards a point and setting the absolute y rotation while doing so and you can't access an object's relative angles in Unity. [As seen here, the blue gizmo always faces the top of the sphere (the centre of the sphere is the point I'm rotating towards)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qjbV.png). I want it to be able to move freely.

Here's my rotation code:

```
Quaternion dir = Quaternion.LookRotation((target - transform.position).normalized) * Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(-90, 0, 0));
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, dir, smooth);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to make a player character able to walk on a ball, like a planets surface?

Comment: I am and I've tried the other solutions, but the problem is I'm trying to add other rotations aswell, and at least the ones I've seen don't really account for that.

Comment: What you could try would be split the player into an empty parent object and a child object showing the player model. Then have the parent object take care of the movement towards the center of the planet. Because the child inherits from the parent, it will then also move towards the center of the planet. This way the parent moves with the child to the center, but the child is able to freely rotate around its own axis. When you move, you can then take the direction the child is looking in and moving the parent forward in that direction. I think this could work with some testing.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that even on child objects the angles are absolute, so even if I try to rotate the child around it's axis it doesn't take it's parents rotation into account and just rotates it in world space, instead of relative to the sphere.

Comment: Transform, which both parent and child has, will have "rotation" and "localRotation", "rotation" is the worldspace rotation. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

I suppose if you rotate the childs localRotation, but then when moving forward use the childs world rotation on the parent, then that might work?

Comment: It does, but the problem is that it also adds the spin onto the child and constraining the y rotation again just constrains it's y angle in world space, not in local space

Comment: Nevermind I managed to fix it by like this:
Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, (target - transform.position).normalized) * transform.rotation;

When I tried this before I used Vector3.up, instead of transform.up, so that's probably what went wrong.
Anyway thanks for your help